# How do I setup an Outlook macro to run when I'm on holidays?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, macros

I have setup an Outlook rule that runs a 'save attachment' Outlook macro when a file with a specific subject line is received.
This is working fine due to the comprehensive answers already logged on this site and used by me to set it up.

Now I want to go on holidays, take my notebook and still have the macro run whenever these emails match the rule.

I understand that this is a client side rule because the macro needs my Outlook open to be able to run.

Is there a method/way/program that will allow me to enjoy my holiday by running this rule and macro without my PC/Outlook running?

Comment: Just leave the computer turned off. Once you are back from holiday start the computer and it should resume where it was and handle your emails as it did before. Outlook only knows it's a new email, it doesn't care that it was sent 2 weeks ago

Comment: Run a rule on the server, if the email provider allows

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that this is a client side rule because the macro needs
> my Outlook open to be able to run.
>
> Is there a method/way/program
> that will allow me to enjoy my holiday by running this rule and macro
> without my PC/Outlook running?

those two sentences are contradictory; no there is no way for that. The macro is a script which **runs on a computer**, if the computer is off, the script can not run. Full stop.

What about running the macro when you return from your holiday?

Comment: Yes, I understand they are contradictory. That’s my issue, trying to find a way for the macro to run without turning the computer on. I could re-create the rule and macro on another Pc but I was wondering if there is another method so I didn’t need to rely on another Pc being on

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

I think I will set the rule and macro up on another PC that I know will be on and then set a rule in my outlook that forwards these emails to the other PC. Of course the forwarding rule will run from the server side.  This should fire the required rule and macro...cheers